# What is the best way to call a function and render a child component onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-component

I have the below code, I want to call a function and render a child component onCLick. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
import AddOrder from './AddOrder'

return (
<Button onClick={handleCheckout}>Checkout</Button>
)

const handleCheckout = () => {
        <AddOrder />
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                items: data?.getUser ? data.getUser.cart : cart,
                email: currentUser ? currentUser.email : undefined,
            }),
        })
            .then(async (res) => {
                if (res.ok) return res.json();
                const json = await res.json();
                return await Promise.reject(json);
            })
            .then(({ url }) => {
                window.location = url;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e.error);
            });
    };
```

I tried making a new function called handleAll and adding it like this:

```
function handleAll(){
   handleCheckout()
   <AddOrder />
}
```

AddOrder.js:

```
function AddOrder() {
  const d = new Date();
  let text = d.toString();
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(queries.GET_USER_BY_ID, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    variables: {
        id: currentUser.uid
    },
});
const [addOrder] = useMutation(queries.ADD_ORDER); 
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hi')
})
if(error) {
    return <h1> error</h1>;
   }
   
if(loading) {
    return <h1> loading</h1>;
   }
if (data){
let newCart = []
for(let i=0; i< data.getUser.cart.length; i++){
    newCart.push({quantity: data.getUser.cart[i].quantity, _id: data.getUser.cart[i]._id})
}
console.log(newCart)
  addOrder({
    variables: {
        userId: currentUser.uid, status: 'ordered', createdAt: text, products: newCart
    }
  });
  console.log("hello")
}
}
export default AddOrder;
```

This did not work either. When I reload this it add 3 copies of the same order to the mongodb collection. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I think your code has many fundamental issues. And you should not expect the stackoverflow community to fix application-specific code of this scale. Your code formatting is quite poor as well, so that really doesn't help your case. I recommend you to spend some more time going through react tutorials, and focus on functional components and the useEffect hook. Learn how react components are rendered on a webpage, rather than just writing code blindly. It will save you time in the future if you first learn how to write react correctly.

Comment: oh ok, won't write code blindly, thank you for the advice